# return number of items in a sub-list at given index i, if any, else 0;

Tags: java, arraylist, junit

> With my workin gout i get IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 out of bounds for length 1

```
public static int getSize (ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> list, int i) {
    if(list == null || list.size() == 0 ) {
        return 0;
    }
    if (!list.get(i).isEmpty()) 
        return list.get(i).size();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the input?

Comment: Note that the for loop, if executed, always returns on its first iteration. You could replace the loop with `if (!list.get(i).isEmpty()) return list.get(i).size();`.

Comment: Why do a method? Why not  `int size = list.get(i).size()`?  Assuming of course that at there are at least  `i+1` lists and no nulls.  Or do you want to count the number of items in the sublist that are equal to 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the number of items in a sublist do the following. This ensures that all values are valid and returns 0 or the size of the sublist.

```
public static int getSize (ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> list, int i) { 
   if (list != null && !list.isEmpty() && i < list.size() && i >= 0) {
         if (list.get(i) != null) {
             return list.get(i).size();
         }
   }
   return 0;  
}
```

You can remove any checks for conditions you are certain will never occur.

Comment: I'm trying to return the number of items in sub-list at index i. if any, else returning 0. Also without importing List

Answer (score 0):

If the array you're passing the function has zero indices, it will throw that error.  0 is the first item and since there isn't a first item it throws that error.

You'll notice that it's likely throwing that error at the for loop.  I'd set a break point and run the debugger to see what the value of list is when you're calling this function.

Answer (score 0):

If you are passing in input an *empty list* as first parameter and *0* as second parameter you will get the error you said: *IndexOutOfBoundsException: index 0 out of bounds for length 0*. Maybe you are in this situation? Here a Junit test which throws the same Exception:

```
  @Test
  public void getSizeTest() {
    getSize(new ArrayList<>(), 0);
  }

  public static int getSize (ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> list, int i) {
    for(int j = 0; j < list.get(i).size(); j++) {
      if(!(list.get(i).get(j).equals(0))) {
      }
      return(list.get(i).size());
    }
    return 0;
  }
```